# facebook api FB.ui Feed Dialog description max length

Tags: facebook, api, fb.ui

What is the maximum length of characters may be in the "description" in FB.ui

```
var obj = {

          description: 'Max lenght???.'
        };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tested and documented it today. Please find below for the fb.ui feed dialog:

a) the max lenght of the first line, assuming that the line consists of multiple words. long words are truncated much quicker.

b) the total length that is never truncated in the dialog.

## Listing:

- Field Name (title): first line: 50c, total length: 75c.
- Caption: first line: 50c, total length: 75c.
- Description: first line: 50c, total length: 512c (possibly more, but hey who needs more than 512 characters).

## Bonus:

- Picture dimensions: 90x90 pixels. It is recommended to refer to an image with 2x 3x that resolution for optimal display but remember it must have squared dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

It has no max length I think, but after around 205-208 characters, it puts 3 dots in the text and rest of the text can be viewed on clicking "see more" link. It actually puts a "see more" link there if there is a long long description.